# Fiddler2: Editing url in AutoResponder

Tags: url-rewriting, fiddler, auto-responder

I am looking for a way to change url in in Fiddle AutoResponder.

Change localhost to external url. Example screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to change the Rule's `Match Condition` simply select the rule, and in the `Rule Editor` box at the bottom of the screen, edit the URL in the top box as desired and click `Save`. For instance, remove `Exact:http://localhost` from the front and the remainder of the URL will be matched instead.

If your goal is to change an in-flight request's URL from one to another (e.g. retargeting a request from one server to another) update the bottom `Action` dropdown in the `Rule Editor` box.

Comment: I must be blind, I just couldn't see that line at the bottom.